# How to serialize async in C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, serialization

I'm using json to write data that the user enters. I want this to be done with `SerializeAsync`. But how can I best do this based on this code?

This is my code without `SerializeAsync`

```
public static bool TempFileExists()
{
    return File.Exists(TempJsonPath());
}

public static async Task WriteToTempJsonAsync(DeclarationJoined declaration)
{
    if (TempFileExists())
    {
        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(declaration);
        File.WriteAllText(PaymentCardListPath(), json);
    }   
}
```

And this is what I have tried

```
public static async Task WriteToTempJsonAsync(DeclarationJoined declaration)
{
    if (TempFileExists())
    {
        Stream writer = new FileStream(TempJsonPath(), FileMode.Append);
        await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(writer, declaration);
    }
}
```

Every time I do this `SerializeAsync` I got a sharing violation. How can I do this asynchronously?

Comment: In the `FileStream` constructor specific `useAsync: true`

Comment: @PeterCsala how should my filestream be then because then i need to add a filebuffer and fileacces also

Comment: `new FileStream(TempJsonPath(), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true)` if use this [ctor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-filestream-ctor(system-string-system-io-filemode-system-io-fileaccess-system-io-fileshare-system-int32-system-boolean))

Comment: using that i got a sharingViolation exception any fix on that ? @PeterCsala

Comment: Are you reading the same file from another stream?

Comment: yes, the file must be add things on different places @PeterCsala

Comment: What should i change to achieve this

Comment: Then you have to change the FileShare from None to `ReadWrite` or `Write` in both places

Comment: i edited the code based on your answer now i  got this exception `System.Text.Json.JsonException: ''{' is invalid after a single JSON value. Expected end of data. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 12426.'`` @PeterCsala

Comment: It says that you can have only 1 top level json object. So, either you have use [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/) or create a new file for each json object